# I want to get a list of public areas within the range of some X km of given coordinates (Lat and Long) in Java and Spring Boot(gradle) by using Mapbox

Tags: java, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have tried this code; it gives some place but not near the given coordinates.(Lat and Long)

```
public List<Point> getCoordinates2() { 
    List<Point> points=new ArrayList<>(); 
    MapboxGeocoding mapboxGeocoding = MapboxGeocoding.builder() 
            .accessToken(accessToken) 
            .query(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_POI)            
            .country("IN") // ISO 3166 alpha 2 country code for India  
            .proximity(Point.fromLngLat(78.4983,  17.4399)) 
            .build(); 
 
    try { 
        GeocodingResponse response = mapboxGeocoding.executeCall().body(); 
        if (response != null && response.features().size() > 0) { 
            for (int i = 0; i < response.features().size(); i++) { 
                CarmenFeature feature = response.features().get(i); 
                String placeName = feature.placeName(); 
                Point point = (Point) feature.geometry(); 
                points.add(point); 
                String coordinates = String.format("%f,%f", point.longitude(), point.latitude()); 
                System.out.println(placeName + ": " + coordinates); 
            } 
        } 
    } catch (IOException  e) { 
 
    } 
 
    return points; 
}
```

For this it gave response like this but we want public areas like parks, theaters, bus stops, railway stations, and temples that are within the range of some X km of given coordinates (Lat and Long)

```
`Point Pleasant Restaurant, Hyderabad, Telangana 500034, India: 78.444396,17.415243
PNT Colony, Vijayawada, NTR, Andhra Pradesh, India: 80.639416,16.538129
Poibeda, Machh Kund, Koraput, Odisha, India: 82.540986,18.584619
Poigai, Vellore, Vellore, Tamil Nadu, India: 79.053124,12.915003
Poigainallur, Arakonam, Ranipet, Tamil Nadu, India: 79.564364,12.903959`
```

and also tried this one   this code-generating POIs are related to the given coordinates and contained in the bbox, but they are limited to 10 records.

```
public List<Point> getCoordinates() {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String parksTemplesHotelsInJPnagar = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/park%20and%20temple%20and%20hotels.json?bbox=77.449061%2C12.848347%2C77.695739%2C12.966143&limit=50&proximity=77.5724%2C12.907252&autocomplete=false&access_token="+accessToken;
        
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(parksTemplesHotelsInJPnagar)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String responseBody = response.body().string();

            JSONArray features = new JSONObject(responseBody).getJSONArray("features");

            for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feature = features.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray coordinates = feature.getJSONArray("center");
                Point point = Point.fromLngLat(coordinates.getDouble(0), coordinates.getDouble(1));
                points.add(point);
                String placeName = feature.getString("text");
                System.out.println(placeName + ": " + point.longitude() + ", " + point.latitude());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return points;
    }
```

It gave response like this but we want more records its limited upto 10 records.

```
Banashankari Temple: 77.573312, 12.915979
Ragiguda Temple: 77.593409, 12.91467
Dharmagiri Manjunathaswamy Temple: 77.564309, 12.921
Venkateshwara Swamy Temple: 77.589474, 12.910329
Laxman Rao Park - Pride of JAYANAGAR: 77.580493, 12.918529
Lakshman Rao Park Jayanagar: 77.578719, 12.918843
Raagi Gudda Prasanna Anjaneya Temple: 77.593239, 12.915066
KS Layout Park 2: 77.559655, 12.906428
Devagiri Temple: 77.567178, 12.926082
ISKCON @ Vaikunta Hill: 77.549434, 12.89312
```

I want to get a list of famous and public areas like parks, theaters, bus stops, railway stations, and temples that are within the range of some X km of given coordinates (Lat and Long) in Java and Spring Boot (gradle) by using Mapbox?

Comment: you may try to create a minimized example (only the API, not the code) if the result of the http query checks out, you may be able to refine your question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).